# Android back button back to search results?

Tags: android

In my android app I have a search interface where each list item can be clicked which launches a new Activity which displays more info on that single item. I have a back button on the New Activity which I would like to go back to the search results list. I've tried an intent that goes back to the searchpage, but that starts a new search:

```
    Intent backIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SearchPage2.class); 
backIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
startActivityForResult(backIntent, 0);
SearchTaDa.this.finish();
```

I've also tried just `SearchTaDa.this.finish();` and `finish();` but both of these closes the whole app. Does anybody know how I can get back to the search results with a Back button click?

Comment: Don't call `finish()` on `SearchTaDa` after starting the second activity.

Comment: How are you starting your detail info Activity? Are you using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP? Because just using finish() should work if you start the Activity normally, not using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. If finish() closes your App, it means it is the topmost Activity.

Comment: there many ways, one of which is overwrite backpressed or you could manipulate its lifecycle referring to the activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**do** not use this code because it removes all the activities which are in the stack

```
backIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Use this code instead:

```
Intent backIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SearchPage2.class); 
startActivityForResult(backIntent, 0);
SearchTaDa.this.finish();
```

Comment: I think all four of you are right. I've removed `finish();` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` from both my SearchPage2 activity and the SearchTaDa activity, but the back button is still bringing me back to a new search, rather than the results. I think that's because I'm not implementing the search function correctly. I'm using SearchManager and `onSearchRequested();` to launch the search. I think rather than doing that I should just use an EditText and a button, then maybe your solutions will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this and try pressing back button on SearchPage2

```
Intent backIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SearchPage2.class); 
startActivityForResult(backIntent, 0);
```

Don't clear the stack nor call finish on previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your other Activity, from which you start the Detail Info Activity. Maybe you are calling finish() there after starting the new Activity, which removes it from the Stack, so you can't go back to it.
You should then be able to use finish() in the second Activity to go back.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want your button to emulate the devices's BACK button, because pressing devices's BACK button should return you to search results activity.

Not sure if it will work, but here's a trick:
In your "more info" activity override the `onBackPressed()` method which calls the `super.onBackPressed()`, then in the click listener of you back putton call: `onBackPressed()`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

//.........
myBackButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(){
    onBackPressed()
  }
});
```

And remove the `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`, when starting the "more info" activity.